# How do I get the requested url from my MembershipProvider class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I'm currently trying to implement the MembershipProvider class, but my user repository isn't typical to most of the examples I'm finding on the net. Instead of retrieving a user, we simply check the user's identity against an auth server for the requested URL:

- User attempts to "POST" to `ws.example.com/jobA`
- Attribute validates the user with the auth server to see if they have access to this action/url
- Rejects or accepts the request

A couple other posts pointed me in this direction for implementing a custom membership provider. The way I figure it, in order to make this work, I need to be able to see what the requested URL was, and be able to look at their cookies. In Filters, i have access to the HttpRequestMessage. How do I get at the info i need in this context??

Comment: Did you try `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` obviously?

Comment: Your problem seems related to authorization whereas membership deals with authentication (who). You should probably handle authorization issues in the AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: Well it depends on how you look at it. It's a token system, but the tokens are issued on every unique request, per url. So what's happening on the first authentication, the user is issued a refresh token which is used for subsequent requests. The resource authorization is issued on every unique call.

Comment: @abatishchev, unfortunately this doesn't really work. If the user opens a page before authenticating, they get forwarded to the login page, and the login page calls a different action, so the Uri is different than the originally requested uri by then. I'm going to see if I can use a redirect paramenter to hold it.

Answer (score 0):

[Despite this thread is not specifically about SharePoint Membership Providers, I will just leave this solution here because I couldn't find it anywhere else, and kept being redirect to this thread while looking for solutions on Google. I hope it helps someone]

For SharePoint Membership Providers, we have the Security Token Service, which is a WCF Service. In this case, System.Web.HttpContext.Current is always null, but you can get the actual Request URL using this property:

```
 System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext
```